# How to check if a page exist in a custom server using Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

Using `next@9.1.7` with a custom server with express. How can I know in my `server.js` if the next.js page exists or not before the `handle(req, res)` call?

I tried with `app.router.execute` but it always returns false. So I imagine that is not the way. I checked the Next.js docs and I didn't get any solution... Does somebody have an idea?

```js
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const server = express()
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

// ...

server.get('*', async (req, res) => {
  const { url, fixed } = fixUrl(req)

  // pageExists is always false ...
  const pageExists = await app.router.execute(req, res, req.url) 

  // Fix the url and redirect only if the page exists 
  // (to avoid redirects to 404 pages)
  if (fixed && pageExists) {
    res.redirect(301, url)
    return
  }

  handle(req, res)
})
```

Comment: i know that is not an elegant solution, but what about check the response.statusCode? basically you do a request to the current route and check status code.

Comment: I tried on the `res.end` event. But looks that redirecting with a 301 after status 200 is getting an error: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: what i mean is something like this `var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
      fetch(fullUrl).then((res) => { 
         status = res.status; 
         console.log( res.status  )
      }).catch((err) => {
       // handle error for example
       console.error(err);
    });`

Also note that this check should not be done inside `server.get('*'` because it will check all requests (css, imgs, ecc...) instead you  should do this check inside routes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved with:

```js
const glob = require('glob')
const path = require('path')

// ...
const pagesDir = path.resolve(`${__dirname}/../src/pages`)
const pages = glob.sync(`${pagesDir}/**/*.js`)
  .map(p => p
    .replace(pagesDir, '')
    .replace('index.js', '')
    .replace('.js', '')
  )

// ...

server.get('*',(req, res) => {
  const { url, fixed } = fixUrl(req)

  if (fixed && pages.includes(url.split('?')[0])) {
    res.redirect(301, url)
    return
  }

  handle(req, res)
})
```

If somebody knows a more elegant solution it will be welcome.

Comment: Right now this is not the best solution because it doesn't work well with dynamic routes

Answer (score 0):

This terrible hack doesn't strictly tell you whether a route exists before calling `handle`, but it does let you hook in and apply your own custom handling of 404 errors before next renders anything to the `res`.

```
const errorRenderer = app.server.renderErrorToHTML;
app.server.renderErrorToHTML = function(err, req, res, pathname, query) {
    if (res.statusCode == 404) {
        // handle the 404 however you like
        return null;
    } else {
        return errorRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```